# How to expose/Invoke c++ COM object/Methods in to .Net core Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, com

`[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("D4AE11C0-FCED-11D3-BAE5-0050DAC5FD84")]
    [TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FCanCreate)]
    public class URSCookiesClass : IURSCookies, URSCookies
    {
        public URSCookiesClass();

```
    [DispId(1)]
    public virtual void Init(string bstrPassword);
    [DispId(2)]
    public virtual string Encrypt(string bstrInput);
    [DispId(3)]
    public virtual string Decrypt(string bstrInput);
}
```

`How to invoke above COM Dll methods in to .net core application.

Comment: Support for COM in .NET core is basically very similar to .NET framework. Note the `dynamic` keyword doesn't work (yet): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12587. try to work a bit on the quality of your question if you need more help

Comment: The same COM Dll we are using it in .net framework by adding as dll reference in to .net framework project. but in .net core it is not working. i am not able to create a object instance for the URSCookiesClass Class